# Sorting an "almost sorted" array in sub linear time

Tags: algorithms, sorting, check-my-answer

I am given an "almost sorted" array with the condition that each element is no more than $k$ places away from its position in the sorted array. I need to show that it is impossible to sort this array in sublinear time asymptotically.

My proof is to suppose a sorted array of length $n$. 
Now assume that every second element is swapped with the element on its left. 
The new array is almost sorted. To sort it would require a minimum of $n/2$ swaps - asymptotically linear amount of operations. Therefore, no sublinear sorting algorithm exists.

Is this proof correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is correct, but you should be careful to stipulate that the swaps are performed in a non overlapping fashion; if the swaps overlap then one element can be carried across the array breaking the guarantee.

Comment: Thank you, perhaps i did not explain well but the swaps can not overlap as i swap two adjecent elements: element one with two, three with four, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct, but more complicated than it needs to be.

Consider an array of $n$ elements which is sorted except for that *one* (unknown) pair of elements is swapped.

Since the sorting algorithm does not know in *which* pair of elements is swapped, any individual element of the array may be in the wrong place. So, we have to make $O(n)$ comparisons to check if each element needs to be moved or not.

Therefore, the complete algorithm cannot be faster than $O(n)$.

The condition that "each element is no more than $k$ places away from its position" is irrelevant, though it might mislead you to waste time looking for a faster algorithm which depends on that condition!

Comment: But this is actually not trivial to formally prove -- I think the original one may be just as easy.